# modular programming in ocaml

Tags: types, module, namespaces, ocaml

I found something which I don't really understand while working on an `ocaml` project.

Suppose I'm using both the `Array` and `List` modules of OCaml standard library. They both implement the function `length` but have different types.
In the `List` module, this is its type:

```
length: a' list -> int
```

And in the `Array` module, it has the type:

```
length: a' array -> int
```

But then I wanted you use both modules in the same module I was implementing, via the `open` keyword:

```
open List
open Array
```

When I tried to use the `length` function on a list, I had a type error during compilation.
Since OCaml is a strong statically typed language, I'm wondering why the compiler didn't know I wanted the length function of the list module since I declared I was using both.

Comment: “I'm wondering why the compiler didn't know I wanted the length function of the list module since I declared I was using both” Yes, but what would be the type of `fun s -> length s` in this context then?

Comment: Based on the answer of jrouquie, it'll be `a' array -> int`

Comment: Exactly, but in the case of an hypothetical OCaml compiler that tried to guess, there would be no single most general type in the OCaml type system for the function. You may be interested by Haskell's solution to this annoyance, type classes: http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: @PascalCuoq: you can do what Haskell does in OCaml with functors and module types, except that you will have to specify the instance of type class manually instead of being inferred

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OCaml does not choose one function or another based on their types.

When you write

```
open Array
```

the functions of module `Array` are masking the ones of module `List` with the same name.
When you later call the function `length`, OCaml looks for a function named `length`, finds `Array.length`, and complains that this function does not have a compatible type.

The usual way is to call `List.length` (instead of just `length`) if that is the function you need.

More generaly, OCaml does not have name overloading (i.e. having two functions or operators with the same name but distinct argument types), in particular because this would make type inference much harder.

Comment: Also: Try to avoid opening modules -- it makes reading your code much harder because a reader must remember which modules are open (and in which order); also as a reader you don't realize immediately where a function came from (from which open-ed module that is).

Comment: I would like to add that opening modules is fine if the origin of the values/functions used remains clear. So don't open modules like List or Array which provide functions with generic names, but "open Printf" is perfectly fine because it provides functions printf, fprintf, etc. whose origin is obvious.